# Change the driver in the connection string to a data source in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, connection-string, driver

I have code which has the driver in a connection string.

```
dim s as string = "Driver={SQL Server}; 
Server=xxx\SQLEXPRESS; 
Database=dbRegister;
```

Trusted_Connection=yes"

I need to change that to:

```
data source=1.2.3.4;
user id=xx;
password=xxxxx;
initial catalog=xxxxx;
```

Connect Timeout=30"

When I just change the text, it gives this error:

```
    [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and 
                                     no default driver specified
```

How do I declare the datasource?

Comment: Curious, what is the motivation for changing this?

Answer (score 0):

> Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial
>   Catalog=myDataBase;User
>   Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Use serverName\instanceName as Data Source to connect to a specific SQL Server instance.

Are you using SQL Server 2005 Express? Don't miss the server name syntax Servername\SQLEXPRESS where you substitute Servername with the name of the computer where the SQL Server 2005 Express installation resides.

visit

> http://www.connectionstrings.com/

for all types of connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your instance name, i.e., `Data Source=1.2.3.4\SQLEXPRESS`.